# Drawing a TicTacToe-field with UTF-8 symbols in C

Tags: c, arrays, utf-8, tic-tac-toe, wchar-t

I have a little TicTacToe game and draw the TicTacToe field with the standart ANSII symbols.
 This is my normal `drawfield` function:

```
void drawField(char *field) {

printf("            ________________________\n");
printf("            |       |       |      |\n");
printf("            |   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[0], field[1], field[2]);
printf("            |_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("            |       |       |      |\n");
printf("            |   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[3], field[4], field[5]);
printf("            |_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("            |       |       |      |\n");
printf("            |   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[6], field[7], field[8]);
printf("            |_______|_______|______|\n");

}
```

Our Tutor/Mentor on my university just made the same field with UTF-8 characters like ┌ ┐└ ┘├, ... . He did this on his Mac coded the whole thing in the simple Apple Texteditor, Gnu-Compiler. So I asked him to send me the code for his drawField function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
char* getcharacter(char character){
switch(character){
    case 'x':
        return "\u2620";
    case 'o':
        return "\u2622";
    case '0':
        return "\u24EA";
    case '1':
        return "\u2460";
    case '2':
        return "\u2461";
    case '3':
        return "\u2462";
    case '4':
        return "\u2463";
    case '5':
        return "\u2464";
    case '6':
        return "\u2465";
    case '7':
        return "\u2466";
    case '8':
        return "\u2467";
    default:
        return " ";
   }
}

void drawField(char *field){
printf("\033[H\033[J");
printf("\u250F\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2533\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2533\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2513\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[0]), getcharacter(field[1]), getcharacter(field[2]));
printf("\u2523\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u252B\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[3]), getcharacter(field[4]), getcharacter(field[5]));
printf("\u2523\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u252B\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[6]), getcharacter(field[7]), getcharacter(field[8]));
printf("\u2517\u2501\u2501\u2501\u253B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u253B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u251B\n");
}
```

Im coding in Visual Studio 2015 and for me the \u Escape Sequences dont work of course - they are just a bunch of ?, ... .

So I tried this to get at least the symbols inside the fields working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
wchar_t sym = ' ';
wchar_t getcharacter(char character) {
switch (character) {
case 'X':
    sym = L'\u2620';
    return sym;
case 'O':
    sym = L'\u2622';
    return sym;
case '1':
    sym = L'\u2460';
    return sym;
case '2':
    sym = L'\u2461';
    return sym;
case '3':
    sym = L'\u2462';
    return sym;
case '4':
    sym = L'\u2463';
    return sym;
case '5':
    sym = L'\u2464';
    return sym;
case '6':
    sym = L'\u2465';
    return sym;
case '7':
    sym = L'\u2466';
    return sym;
case '8':
    sym = L'\u2467';
    return sym;
case '9':
    sym = L'\u2468';
    return sym;
default:
    sym = ' ';
    return sym;
    }
}

void drawField(char *field) {
printf("\033[H\033[J");
printf("\u250F\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2533\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2533\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2513\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[0]), getcharacter(field[1]), getcharacter(field[2]));
printf("\u2523\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u252B\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[3]), getcharacter(field[4]), getcharacter(field[5]));
printf("\u2523\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u254B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u252B\n");
printf("\u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503 %s \u2503\n", getcharacter(field[6]), getcharacter(field[7]), getcharacter(field[8]));
printf("\u2517\u2501\u2501\u2501\u253B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u253B\u2501\u2501\u2501\u251B\n");
}
```

I have to admit that I have no idea about UTF-8 printing in C - could someone help me?

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16, so you need to adjust your code to that.

Comment: But aren't they Unicode escape sequences?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, those are Unicode points. Encoding to a platform specific encoding is a bad idea. The i/o libs usually deal with output encoding

Comment: Does this help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx?

Comment: Didn't you get Compiler warning c4566 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4566);k(vs.output)&rd=true)?

Comment: Not after using wchar_t @werner henze

Comment: drawField is printing out string literals which are const char but into which you try to put 16 bit Unicode chars. My MSVC Compiler emits a C4566 for that.